# Android: Generating PDF from base64 string does not contain formatting

Tags: java, android

I have the following code in my android application (Capacitor):

```
import com.getcapacitor.JSObject;
import com.getcapacitor.Plugin;
import com.getcapacitor.PluginCall;
import com.getcapacitor.PluginMethod;
import com.getcapacitor.annotation.CapacitorPlugin;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Base64;

@CapacitorPlugin(name = "Echo")
public class EchoPlugin extends Plugin {

  @PluginMethod()
  public void echo(PluginCall call) {
    // Get the base64 string from the call
    String base64data = call.getString("value");
    assert base64data != null;
    String base64WithoutPrefix = base64data.replaceFirst("data:application/pdf;base64,", "");
    try {
      // Create a PDF document
      Document document = new Document();
      File outputFile = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), "output.pdf");
      PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
      document.open();

      // Convert base64 string to a byte array
      byte[] pdfData = new byte[0];
      if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        pdfData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64WithoutPrefix);
      }

      // Add the base64 data to the PDF
      document.add(new Paragraph(new String(pdfData)));

      // Close the PDF document
      document.close();

      // Return the path to the generated PDF file
      JSObject ret = new JSObject();
      ret.put("value", outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
      call.resolve(ret);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // Handle any exceptions
      call.reject("PDF generation failed: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

the files is created and opens but the PDF formatting is not there. Instead it just prints out the formatting in the document like in the picture attached.

Wondering if anyone can help resolve this.

[image: Example output]

Thanks